# PHP script: Display images from folder with limit and <next> navigation

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my current php script that will display all images from a folder into a table. However, there are a lot of images and the load time is really slow. How can I limit the number of images displayed and create a dynamic  navigation feature? Thanks!!

```
<?php
$files = glob("images/*.*");
for ($i = 1; $i < count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    $supported_file = array(
        'gif',
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'png'
    );

    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
        echo '<td><a href="' . $image . '"><img src="' . $image . '" alt="Random image" width=200 /></a></td>';
    }
    if ($i % 5 === 0) {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I guess this problem is not easily removed. The most time probably is used by collecting (glob) the file names. As an alternative, you could do the glob only at certain intervals, save the result in a flat file, and use this between the intervals. A flat file could be read into an array, where you could use an offset provided by a $_GET variable. And the glob could be done after you sent all output to the client (kind of offline for the user).

Comment: You say "the load time is slow". Do you mean that the PHP script runs slowly, and the HTML pages takes time to be sent to the browser. Or do you mean the PHP script time is OK but the rendering of the web page is slow because there are lots of images the browser has to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also save the `$files` variable in the `$_SESSION` array. Something like

```
if (empty($_SESSION['files'])) {
  $files = glob("images/*.*");
  ... code for cleaning the $files array based on extension ...
  $_SESSION['files'] = $files;
} else {
  $files = $_SESSION['files'];
}
```

Then check the size of the `$files` and create links based on the size you want.

```
<a href="/whatever?page=2">2</a>
```

Then use the `$_GET['page']` variable to determine the desired set of images to display.